# Understanding mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I have the following directory structure:

```
/var/www/html/
   Project/
       MVC/
           AppDir/
               Controllers/
               Models/
               Views/
           Public/
               index.php
```

I have the following code in my apache configuration file

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/Project/MVC">
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

          RewriteEngine on
          RewriteBase /Project/MVC/Public/

          RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^Public/img/[0-9a-zA-Z]+\.jpg$
          RewriteRule ^.+$ index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

This causes an infinite redirect loop. It also does not do any redirection when connecting directly to the base MVC directory: http://example.com/Project/MVC/

However, if I move the index.php file to the MVC directory and change the RewriteBase to look like this:

```
          RewriteBase /Project/MVC/
```

There is no more redirection loop issue. And, as a side effect of the index being in my web directory it loads my index.php when connecting to the above URL. However, I would prefer the index.php to be in my public directory.

I realize that I can use a directive like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

But I want to dissallow direct access of existing files and just redirect everything to Public/index.php. How can I do this?

Comment: "But I want to disallow direct access of existing files..." You've already got a directory layout that quarantines your public content, so all you should need to do is set your DocumentRoot to /var/www/html/Project/MVC/Public. I.e., if you've got files in Public that you don't want Apache to serve, why are they in Public?

Comment: @AlexHowansky The main reason is because I have other HTML files in /var/www/html that are separate from this project that I also need access to.

Comment: Serve your project from its own vhost. Your models/views/controllers should not be in a directory that's under doc root.

Comment: Okay, I guess I will do that. It was just a testing environment so wasn't wanting to set up a separate subdomain for it. Thanks!

Comment: Note, create a separate doc root too. I.e., like mydomain.com points to /var/www/html and myproject.mydomain.com points to /var/www/myproject. If you create a separate vhost but leave its code under /var/www/html, then it will still be available under the other domain.

Comment: Or just run it in a Docker container. :)